# How many different 3-consecutive cells (row wise or column wise) are there in a grid of $n \times n$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many different 3-adjacent cells (row wise or column wise) are there in a grid of $n \times n$?

This is what I have tried

$T(n,n) = 2T(n-1,n) + (n-3)$, ($n-3$ due to one row or column)

$T(n,n) = O(2^n)$.

Thank you.

Comment: What's a 3-consecutive cell?

Comment: means 3 adjacent cells

Comment: Should they all be vertically aligned, or all horizontally aligned, or is a "corner configuration" allowed?

Comment: corners are allowed but all should be vertically or horizontally aligned

Comment: Any why isn't $T(n,n)\le 2n^2$?

Comment: @kimchi lover No this number is going to be exponential , for $n$ rows we have roughly $n$ many combination + columns also + ..

Comment: I don't think you stated your problem very clearly. The posted answers were written by people who suffered under the same misapprehension I did.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you want to count. The only hint we have is your recursive formula $T(n,n) = 2T(n-1,n) + (n-3)$. You say the $n-3$ is from one row or column, but there are $n-2$ ways to choose a block of 3 adjacent cells in a row of $n$. And why the factor $2$? Also, is there supposed to be exactly one such block in every row? Why do you need recursion for this?

Comment: T(n,n) = T(n-1,n)  + n-3 for a row and T(n,n-1)  +n -3 for a column. In a row there are going to be n-3 many blocks

Comment: Then it's not exponential. For rows it's $(n-2)+(n-2)+...+(n-2)$ with $n$ terms, i.e. $n(n-2)$ just like Mees de Vries says in their answer. For columns it is the same. The total is then $2n(n-2)$. Mees also adds on the number of placements for L-shaped 3-cells, but again it is not clear if that is what you want or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontal bars are determined by their left-most cell. There are $n(n-2)$ options for this cell (neither of the two rightmost columns are available). Similarly, there are $n(n-2)$ vertical bars, determined by their top cell. Then there are four possible orientations for a "corner": for each orientation, there are $(n-1)^2$ options for the 'middle' square to be put, namely missing one extreme row and one extreme column.

The total is $6n^2 - 12n + 4$ options.

Comment: Nicely explained.